# Bookshelf.js save one to many relation

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am trying to save a one to many relation
My models are

**Foo**

```
foo = bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: 'foo',
        bar: function () {
            return this.hasMany('bar', 'barId');
        }
```

**Bar**

```
bar = bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: 'bar',
        foo: function () {
            return this.belongsTo('foo', 'barId');
        }
```

What I am trying to do

```
var Foo = { id: 7 }
new Bar({ blah: blah.val  })
                .foo()
                .attach(foo);
```

The error I am getting

`(intermediate value).foo().attach is not a function`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can save data like that. I assume that the table `bar` has `foo_id` column, so all you need to do is

`new Bar().save({ blah: blah.val, foo_id: Foo.id}).then(function(){});`